# Managing Azure API Management cache - store entire response and delete it based on another endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have an Azure API Management, with API connected to Azure Function (I used autogeneration of API from Function App).
In this API I have few endpoints:

- GET /GetEvents
- POST /AddEvent
- ...

The events are added occasionally, but can be accessed quite often so it's a good idea to store them in cache.
**What I want to achieve is to cache entire response of /GetEvents, but be able to invalidate/delete key when a POST for /AddEvent occurs**. I've used cache-store and cache-lookup policies in my previous projects, so it would look like this:

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="app-test" />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" must-revalidate="false" downstream-caching-type="public" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <cache-store duration="@((new Random(context.RequestId.GetHashCode()).Next(40, 50)) * 3 * 60)" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Now I just need to delete the key. I thought I'd use cache-remove-value policy, but it needs to provide a key and when I looked it up in Redis the key looks partially randomly generated something like this:
"3_apimpbdhsanlkcmeaojfcewjfdsabucbeiuaw1qazerfvg.12345678_app-test;rev=1.11111111_get-getevents.12345678_4_https_apim.azure-api.net_443_/app-test/GetEvents". This makes deletion using key troublesome (if not impossible). I thought to use cache-store-value and cache-lookup-value, as they allow to specify the key under which the data will be stored. My issue with that approach is that it also requires to specify which data I want to store and it doesnt accept the Response object. Code below:

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="app-test" />
        <cache-lookup-value key="GetEvents" variable-name="eventsList" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
        <forward-request />
        <!--base: End Global scope-->
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <cache-store-value key="GetEvents" value="@(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Response.Body.AsFormUrlEncodedContent()))" duration="@((new Random(context.RequestId.GetHashCode()).Next(40, 50)) * 3 * 60)" />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I've tried to serialize it, but with no success and it got me thinking if I'm approaching the problem from the right angle. Do I need to serialize/convert to string the response, cache it (using cache-store-value), and then when next request appears retrive it from cache (using cache-lookup-value) instead of contacting backend (using choose and when policy)?

**To summarize I have two questions**:

1. Is there a way to specify the key of cache entry using cache-store, so I can delete it in another endpoint using cache-remove-value policy?
2. Is there a way to store entire response (as in cache-lookup) of one endpoint and invalidate that cache using another endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below policy store the entire response and prevent request to backend if it is not needed.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="afreen-fa" />
        <cache-lookup-value key="GetValue" default-value="not_exists" variable-name="cachedResponse" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("cachedResponse") == "not_exists")">
                <forward-request />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("cachedResponse") != "not_exists")">
                <set-body>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("cachedResponse"))</set-body>
            </when>
            <when condition="@((context.Response.StatusCode == 200) && (context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("cachedResponse") == "not_exists"))">
                <cache-store-value key="GetValue" value="@(context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true))" duration="3600" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

By using this policy I am able to store the entire response.

[image]

You can then remove the cached key or invalidate in your POST call using `<cache-remove-value key=”GetValue” />`

***References***-

[Azure API Management refresh cached response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167922/azure-api-management-refresh-cached-response).

Comment: Thank you! I've added an edit to prevent api from requesting data from backend if there is response cached, but I'm accepting the answer regardless since it helped me and answered my question.